# Status bar has disappeared in apps (Xcode iphone)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Hi i have recently updated Xcode to the latest version and my iPhone software is up to date.

However when i test any of the apps i have built the status bar does not appear (e.g. carrier - time - battery status)

Just wondering if there is a way in settings to turn this back on?

Answer (score 2):

well I try hide the status bar in all my app and in the "app"-info.plist and I add two rows in the dictionary "Information Property List" I add "View controller-based status bar appearance" set YEs and in "Status bar is initially hidden"set NO[image] and for me works n_n'

In this screen short  "View controller-based status bar appearance" is NO make it YES.